# In grub went into system settings and changed priority of boot drives, now only booting to grub rescue. Help?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-cd, grubrescue

Whenever I power on I get this screen, where I can enter commands:

```
error: no such device: e9e6b763-5dcc-821b-acc69c2eaaee.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I have seen some other posts of similar problems, where the answerer told them to boot a liveCD and then do a boot repair. The problem is I don't know how to do that from here, if that's even possible.

I did an ls command and the output was:

```
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt1) (hd2) (hd2,gpt9) (hd2,gpt8) (hd2,gpt7) (hd2, gpt6) (and so on...) (hd2,gpt1)
```

I'd like to get some help in figuring out how to boot my linux LiveCD from this menu. Thanks!

EDIT: This problem has officially been solved, but my low reputation means I cannot answer my own question for an other 8 hours. I will post what I did after that time.

Comment: Have you tried any of this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Comment: Hey, I tried pressing Esc repeatedly as the computer powers on but it still just boots into this "grub rescue" thing. Is that what you meant I should dfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I don't know anything about this grub rescue, but I was able to fix the damage I had done. For any future people that have this problem:

I turned off the laptop. Then I turned on the laptop using the alternative power button that I guess overrides something and enables you to go into BIOS. I then chose to enter BIOS and then rearranged my booting priority to what it was before.

I hope this helps!